# Program to input a number and if its a factorial number then output factorial series else false

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Factorial{

         void factNum(int n){
                int fact=1;
          ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
               for(int i=1;fact<=n;i++){
                     fact=fact*i;
                         al.add(i);
                    if(fact==n){
                        for(int j:al){
                        System.out.print(+j);
                        }}

    }

}

        public static void main(String args[]){

          Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
           Factorial f=new Factorial();
           System.out.println("Enter the Integer");
           int num=scan.nextInt();
           f.factNum(num);
}
}
```

I wrote this code so that when I input number 24 which is factorial I will get 1 2 3 4 as a output and when I input 23 i should get output as false. My code is almost correct but the problem is that when I enter number which does not belong to factorial series, I am not getting False as output. Please can anyone help me where in this code I can keep System.out.print("False"); Statement.

Comment: Don't print a result from `factNum()`.  Have `factNum()` *return* the `ArrayList<Integer>`.  If the returned result has elements, print them.  If it doesn't, print `"False"`.

Comment: You should try formatting the program better to make it easier for people to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flag value as shown in below code to keep track of the condition of whether the number is factorial or not.

```
public static void factNum(int n) {

    int fact = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    boolean flag = false;

    for (int i = 1; fact <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
        al.add(i);
        if (fact == n) {
            flag = true;
            for (int j : al) {
                System.out.print(+j);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!flag)
        System.out.println("false");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing "False" anywhere.Keep a boolean flag to check if the given number is factorial or not and print accordingly.

```
void factNum(int n){
        int fact=1;
        boolean flag = true;
        ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1;fact<=n;i++){
            fact=fact*i;
            al.add(i);
            if(fact==n){
                flag = false;//if factorial then make it false
                for(int j:al){
                    System.out.print(+j);
                }}

        }
        if(flag)
            System.out.println("False");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
void factNum(int n) {
        int fact = 1;
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int check = 0;
        for (int i = 1; fact <= n; i++) {
            fact = fact * i;
            al.add(i);
            if (fact == n) {
                for (int j : al) {
                    System.out.print(+j);
                    check = 1;
                }
            }
            else if (fact>n && check == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("False");            
            }
        }
    }
```